# Avoid no method error when user is not signed in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Just wondering how they do it here:

https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/app/views/layouts/_head_panel.html.haml

specifically,

```
= link_to user_snippets_path(current_user)
```

That's on line 30. I can't see any if statements or anything earlier than it. If they are signed out, won't current_user be nil? They are using devise, but devise does nothing clever in this regard. current_user is nil if no user!

update

Turns out, they have a before_action in their application_controller that calls the devise helper `authenticate_user!` This redirects a non-sighned in user to the sign up page, so they never hit a view that contains `current_user`.

Saying this, what if I wanted my fork of gitlab to allow users to browse the site without being signed in?

Should I use a partial to redner subtly different header bars? Or maybe several helpers to tweak information? Or a decorator. Just a lot of choices here :)

Answer (score 0):

They use the `devise` gem (more informations [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)).

This gem provides lots of helpers to handle users authentication. Two of them are linked to your question:

- The `authenticate_user!` before_filter which will redirect user to a sign_in page unless he is already authenticated.
- The `user_signed_in?` helper which tells you if the current_user is signed in or not.

The `user_signed_in?` helper is similar to `!!current_user`, but is more readable.

So, if you want to let any user to see your site content, you have several solutions:

- Use the `authenticate_user!` before_filter, which will force all users to sign in on your website.

  ```
  def ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!
  end
  ```
- Use the `user_signed_in?` method and render different views depending on the return value.

  ```
  def someAction
    if user_signed_in?
      render :someView
    else
      render :someOtherView
    end
  end
  ```
- Set a default user and display the same template for signed in and non-signed in users

  ```
  def someAction
    @user = current_user || User.new # or maybe something like User.default where default is a User's scope.
  end
  ```

This option may be used carefully concerning database modifications.